# requests_cache: connecting using REDIS_URL

Tags: heroku, redis

I am trying to cache my requests using `requests_cache` and redis like so:

```
requests_cache.install_cache(
    'requests_cache', backend='redis', expire_after=600
)
```

and when Redis is run on `localhost:6379`, everything is fine and works out of the box.

However when I deploy my app to Heroku where there is a REDIS_URL environment variable, the above command fails because obviousle REDIS_URL does not point to `localhost`:

```
Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

So the question is, how do I make it work on Heroku? the docs aren't clear on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an additional argument to `install_cache` called `connection` which will be of `StrictRedis` type. So I guess create it like that:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='REDIS_URL', port=6379, db=0)
requests_cache.install_cache(
    'requests_cache', backend='redis', expire_after=600, connection=r
)
```

Or something similar, depending on how much information `REDIS_URL` contains (protocol, port etc.)